# Changing the value of a key in a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am facing some issues in updating a value in the Nested dictionary.

```
my_dic = {'TypeA': {'Bit0': {'TypeA': {'Bit0': 'A', 'Bit1': 'B', 'Bit2' : 'C'}, 'TypeB': 'D', 'TypeC': 'E'}, 'Bit1': 'F', 'Bit2': 'G'}, 'TypeB': 'H'}
```

I need to update the Dictionary having values A, B and C with a new dictionary

```
new_dic = {Sensor Error: {'Bit0' : 'X', 'Bit1': 'Y', 'Bit2': 'Z'}}
```

I don't want a new function doing this. This comes somewhere inside my processing where I need to update the Dictionary. Can this be done using while loop or for loop? Went through other stack overflow questions. Couldn't find something like this. All of those questions had a function and iterated within a maximum of two layers of the dictionary. The dictionary may be of any depth here.

```
def recursive_lookup(k, d):
if k in d: return d[k]
for v in d.values():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        a = recursive_lookup(k, v)
        if a is not None: return a
return None
```

Tried this code, realized this won't work for any depth. Also, this does not meet my requirement. I don't need a function to find the key and replace it's value.

To elaborate, The dictionary are basically errors and error words.

```
my_dic = {
          'System Error': {
                           'Bit0': 'Out of Sync'
                           'Bit1': {
                                    'Sensor Error':{                                              
                                                    'Bit0': 'Out of Range Error'
                                                    'Bit1': 'Communication Error'
                                                   }
                                    }
                            'Bit2': 'System Unresponsive Error'
                            }
          }
```

This the application of my_dic

Desired Output would be:

```
my_dic = {
              'System Error': {
                               'Bit0': 'Out of Sync'
                               'Bit1': {
                                        'Sensor Error':{                                              
                                                        'Bit0': 'X'
                                                        'Bit1': 'Y'
                                                        'Bit2': 'Z'
                                                       }
                                        }
                                'Bit2': 'System Unresponsive Error'
                                }
              }
```

Comment: can you explain how the `new_dic` got generated?

Comment: It sounds like you need a recursive function to go down into the depths of your data structure.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the question, why does `my_dic['TypeA']['Bit0']['TypeA'] = new_dic` not work?

Comment: I don't want to hard code it that way. There's a file from which i create this dictionary. That data in the file can change and the depth can vary. I want to handle it in a generic way. @CoryNezin

Comment: Yes, I need a recursive function to update it @quamrana

Comment: I read a file and create the new_dict @NarendraPrasath

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana I have updated the question with what I tried

Comment: Why the limitation of "I don't want a new function doing this"? You can't have a recursive function without a function. :)

Comment: @kamion Sorry for the misinformation previously. I don't need a function because this part comes in between processing some other data. I don't prefer a function as of now.

Comment: btw you should always prefer a function.

Comment: @quamrana if a function resolves the issue I'm facing, then I'll be glad to know about it

Comment: so see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your example my_dic is as below. So your lookup `k` is `"TypeA"`? But there's also a `"Bit0"` key nested inside the first level `"TypeA"` dictionary. What is the rule regarding that? I'm not understanding the "lookup rules" you are trying to achieve here.

```
{
    "TypeA": {
        "Bit0": {
            "TypeA": {
                "Bit0": "A",
                "Bit1": "B",
                "Bit2": "C"
            },
            "TypeB": "D",
            "TypeC": "E"
        },
        "Bit1": "F",
        "Bit2": "G"
    },
    "TypeB": "H"
}
```

Lookup rule:

1. First level must have the key `k` ("TypeA")
2. Second level can have any key, but must be a dictionary type, and discard all non-dictionaries?
3. Third level must have the key `k` ("TypeA")?

Comment: I have updated the question with the application example of the dictionary @kamion

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, according to computer science, a recursive function can be transformed into an iterative loop, so perhaps there is a way to accomplish what you want in a loop.

Alternatively its more often better to put distinct functionality into a function, and as I like recursive functions when they match a recursive data structure, this is my solution.

Note that you don't offer any examples of what your data structure looks like after the update, so I've had to guess that part.

This code:

```
def recursiveUpdate(target, keys, update):
    for k in target:
        if k in keys:
            v = target[k]
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                recursiveUpdate(v, keys, update)
            else:
                print(target[k], update[k])
                target[k] = update[k]
        else:
            v = target[k]
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                recursiveUpdate(v, keys, update)
                
my_dic = {
          'System Error': {
                           'Bit0': 'Out of Sync',
                           'Bit1': {
                                    'Sensor Error':{                                              
                                                    'Bit0': 'Out of Range Error',
                                                    'Bit1': 'Communication Error'
                                                   }
                                    },
                            'Bit2': 'System Unresponsive Error'
                            }
          }

new_dic = {'Bit0' : 'X', 'Bit1': 'Y', 'Bit2': 'Z'}

keys = list(new_dic.keys())
recursiveUpdate(my_dic, keys, new_dic)

print(my_dic)
```

produces this output:

```
{'System Error': {'Bit0': 'X', 'Bit1': {'Sensor Error': {'Bit0': 'X', 'Bit1': 'Y'}}, 'Bit2': 'Z'}}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I want is 'Bit0' in 'Sensor Error' to be replaced with the 'new_dic'

Comment: Ok, but why? What are the rules? What about `Bit1` and `Bit2`?

Comment: There's just Bit0 and Bit1 in Sensor Error. I need to change the Bit0 part. Bit0 will have a dictionary(new_dic) as a value now. Bit0 in Sensor Error is changeable and is read from a different file.

Comment: Ok, so how do we tell the program that?

Comment: Excatly my question. What is it that the OP is trying to get to, and what are the criteria that needs to be met to get there. How did the OP arrive at 'Bit0' in 'Sensor Error' needs to be replaced. If we can understand that, then we can help the OP. Otherwise, we're clutching at straws. :)

Comment: In my_dic, Sensor Error can be defined in any Bit in the System Error. Requirement is to replace the value of Bit0 in Sensor Error with new_dic

Comment: I can also move the other Bit(Bit1) in Sensor Error outside of it. So, replacing the entire dictionary of Sensor Error with new_dic would also be helpful.

Comment: So, please update your question with the desired output, consistent with an example original data and an update `dict`.

Comment: @quamrana I have updated the question with the output as well as new_dic dictionary.

Comment: So, this means that your target is always located at a fixed place, so the update could be accomplished easily by: `my_dic['System Error']['Bit1'] = new_dic`

Comment: My target is not fixed. Sensor Error can be either in Bit0 position of System Error or even in Bit2